# Combine a cell array or strings into a single space separated string

Tags: string, matlab, cell-array

How do I combine cells in a cell array to form a one single cell? For e.g.:

```
a = {'I', 'am', 'a', 'noob', 'in', 'matlab'}
```

into 1 cell

```
a = 'I am a noob in matlab'
```

Comment: http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strjoin.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**NOTE** Luis Mendo's answer of `strjoin` below is clearly better, however I can't delete this while it is the accepted answer.

---

First you need to add a row of space characters:

```
a = {'I', 'am', 'a', 'noob', 'in', 'matlab'}
a(2,:) = {' '}
```

And now you can use the `{:}` operation to get a comma separated list and the `[]` operation to concatenate these:

```
[a{:}]

ans = 

I am a noob in matlab
```

Note that this works out because Maltab is [column-major](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Row-major_order#/Column-major_order) which is why when you "linearize" a matrix using the `:` operator, it goes down the columns first before going across the rows.

Also note that this method is slightly flawed in that it adds one extra space character to the end of the result. So you might want to [trim](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strtrim.html) it.

Last thing to note is that you asked for the answer to be in one *cell* but I gave you a char array. If you really want it in a cell, which I'm sure you don't, then do this:

```
{[a{:}]}
```

Comment: :D I was wondering if you would change I am a noob to You are a n00b.

Answer (score 6):

[`strjoin`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strjoin.html) does exactly that:

```
>> a = {'I', 'am', 'a', 'noob', 'in', 'matlab'}
a = 
    'I'    'am'    'a'    'noob'    'in'    'matlab'
>> strjoin(a)
ans =
I am a noob in matlab
```